# Installing Energia for TI MSP430 development

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and I want to install [Energia](http://energia.nu/). I have searched in countless sources and I have tried their solutions but so far I haven't achieved it. In my case I have downloaded the binary release but I don't know what to do, although I searched how to install a binary in Ubuntu. After having the binary release downloaded what can I do after that? Can someone provide a clear way to install it?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions here?: http://energia.nu/guide/guide_linux/

Comment: Which version of the MSP430 do you have? It looks like there are currently 4 on offer at http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp430.html Which pin mappings and board setup instructions you need depend on the version of the board you have.

Comment: @ElderGeek yes I have seen them but I don't understand it, also I don't think it describes the full process. I have the M430G2452.

Comment: How far did you get? What part did you not understand?

Comment: Is this the one? http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp430-msp-exp430g2.html

Comment: @ElderGeek I think that this is the one. I downloaded the binary and have installed the compiler. In one source said that I had to. The tutorial from energia doesn't mention anything about installation, only about drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it but I actually found a solution. Because as I said in the question I have searched extensively and most of the solutions was very messy and unclear I answer my question in the hope that it will help others and save them the hours I spend on this problem myself. This solution was hidden in a thread of a forum:

So in order to install Energia:

1. Download the binary release version from the energia site
2. Open the Ubuntu Software Center
3. Install the "Main Menu" package
4. From the first column select Accessories
5. Click New Item, name it Energia and select the file energia from the unzipped downloaded Energia binary release
6. Select Ok
7. Write Energia in Launcher and click on the Energia entry.

After that one must set up the serial comunication with the Launchpad board. From another source I manage to find a solution to solve that problem doing the following:

1. `sudo lsusb`
2. `sudo modinfo cdc-acm`
3. Then create a file called 71-persistent-msp430.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/ directory
4. Add this line in it:

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="0451", ATTRS{idProduct}=="f432", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"`

5. `sudo adduser user plugdev`

Write your own username instead of user.

6. `sudo service udev restart`

Also it may need to change the Board from Energia's toolbar (Tools and after Board).

Comment: Very good, useful!

Comment: @EricWang I am really happy! I spent hours searching for this myself so I am glad if I helped someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution without "Main Menu".

- download the binary release version from the energia site
- extract .tgz file to your home directory. Rename it "energia"
- In Terminal, run this command

  `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/Energia.desktop`

Copy this,

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Energia
Type=Application
Exec=/home/[your_user_name]/energia/energia
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/[your_user_name]/energia/lib/energia_48.png
Comment=Any comment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=Energia
```

- change [your_user_name] and save it (Ctrl+X).
- And then you can see Energia on Dash, click on it. It should work.